# When do you roll the damage for Cloud of Daggers?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, damage

The cloud lasts up to 1 minute, and specifies 4d4 damage. Is the damage rolled when you cast it, or is it rolled each time an enemy is afflicted by the cloud?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

> A creature takes 4d4 slashing damage when it enters the spell’s area for the first time on a turn or starts its turn there.

This 4d4 damage is per time affected (and per creature), not once for the spell.  You do not roll once when casting the spell and then deal the same damage to the affected creature each time the spell deals damage; you roll once for each instance of damage.  This is true for almost all methods of dealing damage.

Comment: Thanks! This makes sense to me. I guess what got me hung up was how on multi-target affects you "roll damage once for all [targets]" (PHB 196), but it makes sense to consider that more of a "roll once for each instance of damage".

Comment: @alienth Ah, that makes sense.  Yes, I'd rule that that's one instance of damage whereas everyone running into the cloud is damaged separately.  If they all walked into it at once somehow (maybe mass teleportation of some kind?) I might roll once for the group but I'd more likely skip the initial damage and just have them take damage at the start of their turns.

Comment: That rule for damage rolls applies when an "[...] effect deals damage to **more than one target** *at the same time* [...]" (PHB 196; bold emphasis in original, italics mine) It's not just about AoE spells, even something like *magic missile* follows the rule as written.

Answer (score 4):

This question was officially clarified in the [Sage Advice Compendium](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/sac/sage-advice-compendium#SA202):

> **Does [moonbeam](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/moonbeam) deal damage when you cast it?**
>
> ...[N]o.
> Here are some spells with the same timing as moonbeam for their areas of effect:
>
> - blade barrier
> - cloudkill
> - **cloud of daggers**
> - Evard’s black tentacles
> - forbiddance
> - moonbeam [sic]
> - sleet storm
> - spirit guardians

(emphasis in the question in the original; emphasis in the answer mine)

Answer (score -4):

> You fill the air with spinning daggers in a cube 5 feet on
>   each side, centered on a point you choose within range.
>   A creature takes 4d4 slashing damage **when it enters
>   the spell’s area for the first time on a turn or starts
>   its turn there.** (PHB 222)

That means it only takes damage on its turn, either when it starts there, or if it moves into the cloud.

Also a nifty trick: get another party member to grapple the opponent and hold them in the cloud. Or have someone perform a shove to knock them into the cloud. If the cloud is in a corridor, your tank can stand next to the enemy and they will be forced to disengage if they want to leave the cloud.

Comment: It doesn't only take damage on *its* turn. Note the spell says "enters the spell's area for the first time on **a** turn".

Comment: Yeah, it seems like that is the case. Although, the wording there is confusing: how can you move when it's not **a** turn?

Comment: What I mean is that the spell doesn't say "enters the spell's area for the first time on *its* turn". Therefore it can take damage if it's forced to enter the cloud on someone else's turn I.E. via the shove action. So it doesn't take damage *only* on its turn.

Comment: You can move when its not your turn by being pushed or grappled or teleported or any number of other things.

Comment: Yes but what is the difference between "when it enters the spell’s area for the first time on a turn" and "when it enters the spell’s area for the first time"?

When can you move when it is not **a** turn at all? Isn't it always somebody's turn?

Comment: If it didn't have "on a turn" you could enter the cloud one turn take your damage, leave and then next turn reenter the cloud and not take damage because it isn't the first time you entered the cloud. "On a turn" is providing clarification as to how often you can take the damage, not implying there is a way of moving into the cloud outside of turns.

Comment: The above two comments would have been a good Q&A pair for the site.  The really shouldn't be comments, though.

Comment: @ rlbond: Iniative / turn order.  "On a turn," numerous turns in a given round. ABCD where A = ogre, BCD = party. Initiative order BACD.  B casts daggers in square where A stands, A takes damage (B's turn). A moves 5' to attack C.  C casts thunderwave, pushes A into daggers.  A takes damage, (A pushed into blades on a turn (C's),  The thunder wave moved him 10' total, one 5' square further adjacent to D. D shoves the ogre (successfully) back into daggers.  Four turns in one round (each is "a turn"), three separate impacts with cloud of daggers.  Does this make sense? "a turn"

Comment: The example provided by @KorvinStarmast isn't accurate. When B casts daggers where A stands, A doesn't take damage during B's turn because A didn't enter the spell area in B's turn. A will suffer damage on its own turn instead.