# If the Cordon of arrows spell is cast and the target is within range when it's cast would it activate when they move?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, ranged-attack, traps

For context: the target was invisible and near death. So we cast spike growth on the entrance with her in it and followed it up with a cordon of arrows. Basically target became visible and as it's next move it turned into an eagle which was inside of the later spell's range.

The spell's description states:

> ...whenever a creature other than you comes within 30 feet of the
>   ammunition.

So would it only count the first time the enemy enters the range? Or would it also trigger if it was already inside of the trap and come closer?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're missing a crucial part of the spell's description:

> ... whenever a creature other than you comes within 30 feet of the ammunition **for the first time on a turn or ends its turn there**

This means when the creature enters the area, an arrow flies up to strike it. If the creature ends its turn inside the area, another arrow flies up to strike it.

Note that there is no mention of how close a creature needs to be, it only specifies when the creature enters within 30 feet, so even if the creature was running away from the area, as long as it is still inside at the end of its turn, an arrow flies up. So on a turn, a maximum of two arrows can fly up and hit the creature.

Comment: Since it says "or", it could be read as only one arrow a turn.

Comment: "or" is used here to signify that an arrow would activate in either or both cases, since the word "whenever" is used there.

Comment: Most of the answers on [this similar question](http://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/61909/what-does-when-it-enters-the-spell-s-area-for-the-first-time-on-a-turn-or-s/73866) say it is only once on a turn. Though that is on *starting* the turn in the AoE, not *ending* there, it's still similar.

Comment: it's in no way similar, starting and ending activation is very different. The Cloud of Daggers spell is intended to at least hit the creature its AOE is casted on. Cordon of Arrows is more of a "trap" like effect.

Comment: I agree: it's easy to picture a scenario when a creature enters an area and ends their turn within it on the same turn. But to both *start* your turn in an area and also enter that area "for the first time" on the same turn doesn't seem possible (you could argue that if they started in the area, then left and returned in the same turn, this happens: but it seems to me you haven't entered an area "for the first time" if you were already in it. If I say "I am entering this house for the first time this year," I'm at least implying that I haven't *been* in the house earlier in the year.)