# In general, is an AOE's "or" inclusive or exclusive?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, area-of-effect

A few AOE spells use the wording "...when first entering the area ... **or** ending it's turn there". The question is, is this "or" *inclusive*, (A creature that enters and remains for the duration of it's turn will take the damage *twice*), or *exclusive* (the creature will only take damage *once* for entering, even if it ends it's turn in the AOE)?

It seems that if the "or" is exclusive, a creature would have to spend *two* turns in the AOE to trigger the condition "ends it's turn there", which would be an incredibly rare situation.

Some examples:

> **Wall of Fire**:
>
> One side of the wall, selected by you when you cast this spell, deals
> 5d8 fire damage to each creature that ends its turn within 10 feet of
> that side or inside the wall. A creature takes the same damage **when
> it enters the wall for the first time on a turn or ends its turn
> there**. The other side of the wall deals no damage.
>
> **Insect Plague**:
>
> When the area appears, each creature in it must make a Constitution
> saving throw. A creature takes 4d10 piercing damage on a failed save,
> or half as much damage on a successful one. A creature must also make
> this saving throw **when it enters the spell's area for the first time
> on a turn or ends its turn there**.

This question is similar, but unresolved: [How much damage does a creature take for spending its entire turn inside a Wall of Fire?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/138743/how-much-damage-does-a-creature-take-for-spending-its-entire-turn-inside-a-wall)

Comment: I've closed this as a duplicate, the target question is asking the very same thing about one of the spells you mention, *insect plague*.