# A way to get out of taking Cloud of Daggers damage?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells

Suppose Alice, Charlie, and Bob are in combat (in that order).

Alice casts [Cloud of Daggers](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/cloud-of-daggers) centered on Bob. [This](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/130585/when-exactly-does-a-creature-take-the-first-damage-from-cloud-of-daggers) question explains that Bob takes no damage (yet), as merely creating the area doesn't trigger the damage.

Charlie casts [Thunderwave](https://roll20.net/compendium/dnd5e/Thunderwave#content) on Bob, who fails the save. Bob takes 2d8 thunder damage and is pushed 10ft, out of the area created by Cloud of Daggers.

Next is Bob's turn. Would I be correct to say that Bob never takes damage from the Cloud of Daggers (unless he does something silly like run back into it)?

Comment: Related: "[What does "when it enters the spell’s area for the first time on a turn or starts its turn there" mean?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/61909)"

Answer (score 13, accepted):

### Yes

You have interpreted the spell text correctly.

> **Cloud of Daggers** ... A creature takes 4d4 slashing damage when it enters the spell’s area for the first time on a turn or starts its turn there.

Since Bob never uses his movement to enter the cloud and he does not start his turn in the cloud, he will remain undamaged by it.

If Charlie uses [Thunderwave](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/thunderwave) again to push Bob back into the cloud, he would take damage as he “enters” the spells radius.

Comment: Thank you. Spells like this one mess with my head for some reason, I always rule wrong when I'm DMing!